# In a Flask application that is using SQLAlchemy, is it ok to permanently put `session.rollback` at the beginning of the app?

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy, rollback

I'm new to Flask and web development in general. I have a Flask web-application that is using SQLAlchemy, is it ok to put `session.rollback` at the beginning of the app in order to **keep it running** even after a transaction fails?
I had a problem with my website when it stopped working after I was attempting to delete records of one table. The error log showed that the deletion failed due to entries in another table still referencing these records as their foreign key. The error log suggested using `session.rollback` to rollback this change, so I put it at the beginning of my app just after binding my database and creating the session and my website worked. This gave me the hint to leave that line there. Is my move right, safe and ok? Can anyone tell me what is the correct thing to do if this is somewhat endangering the functionality or logic of my website by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say by that you are by definition [cargo cult coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and should try to determine why you're finding these errors in the first place instead of just including a bit of code for a reason you don't understand.

The problem you're describing is the result of using foreign keys to ensure data integrity in your database. Typically SQLAlchemy will nullify all of the depending foreign keys, but since I don't know anything about your set up I can't explain why it wasn't. It is perhaps a difference between databases.

One massive problem with putting the rollback at the beginning of a route (or the entire global app) is that you might rollback data which you didn't want to. You haven't provided an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so no one can really help you debug your problem.

Cargo cult coding in circumstances like this is understandable, but it's never a good practice. To solve this problem, investigate the [cascades](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html) in SQLAlchemy. Also, fire up your actual SQL db interface and look at the data's structure, and set `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = 1` in your config file to see what's actually getting emitted.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Malan, Thank you so much for your answer. In fact, I have solved the bug that caused the internal server error and made the code delete the dependant record upon request so that error is actually solved, hence, the lack of need for MVCE. My question was about future errors of this sort just to keep my website running you know? Because that last error has shot down my website completely. I understand now that this is not a viable solution as you suggested that this is cargo cult coding. Thank you so much for your very helpful info.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the rollback at the beginning but when a database operation fails.
The error is due to an integrity condition in your database. Some rows in your table are being referenced by another table. So, you have to remove referencing rows first.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did already, my question was about future cases because that error has shut my website and I don't want my website to shut down. anyways, I removed that line. thank you so much for your help and clarification